# LINQ Query for an old ADO.NET Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am not used to writing JOIN statements using LINQ. I am trying to convert this old query into LINQ Lambda syntax and struggling to understand how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, u.email, b.date
FROM 
Patients p
LEFT JOIN Users u
ON u.patientid =p.id and u.id=p.primarycontactid
INNER JOIN BillingSettings b ON b.PracticeId = p.id and b.isDue=1
WHERE p.status=1
AND p.appointmentdate > now() and p.appointmentdate < now() + 90
and b.expirationdate < now()
order by p.id
```

Comment: Consider using the query comprehension syntax (`from p in patients`, etc). The Join syntax is a lot simpler to understand with that synax than the functional syntax. Otherwise, you need to know that Stackoverflow isn't a "I have a problem, write some code for me" site. You should try to figure out how to do what you want to do, try to do it, and then, if you have issues,  come back and ask a Stackoverflow question

Comment: Also, don't try to write it all at once ... start with the patients and the patient criteria. When that's done, add the billing settings to the query. When that's done add the user ids ... so, just like regular sql build your query up one piece at a time.

Comment: Query is simple ChatGPT should translate it with ease.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: Oh, and get LinqPad (https://www.linqpad.net/). It's great for incrementally building queries and learning how it all fits together

Comment: @NetMage. That is very helpful indeed! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share your entities as well, so that it would be easier to assist you on this.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv ChatGPT will easily create a bad answer, because the real answer is "ORMs don't need JOINs"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, don't tell me that you never use LINQ joins ;)

Comment: @hillcountry99 LINQ isn't embedded SQL. The ORM itself, EF, will generate any JOINs based on the *entities* and their relations. What are the actual entities? You may be able to write something like `context.Patients.Where(p=>p.AppointmentDate>DateTime.Today && p.AppointmentDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(90) && p.BillingSettings.ExpiratonDate < DateTime.Today && p.BillingSettings.IsDue)`. No joins at all.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv why write LINQ joins for ad-hoc queries when I can use Dapper with the exact SQL I want? When I need object graphs I use an ORM. When I need simple mapping I use Dapper. When I run ETL jobs that work on 500K rows I use raw SQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, when i need ad-hoc queries, I use LINQ vial `linq2db` , when i run ETL jobs, I use `linq2db` and again LINQ. Writing SQL become too boring and verbose.

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this without compiler so it can be wrong but generally your answer is below.

```cs
var now = DateTime.Now();

var query = 
    from p in db.Patients 
    join u in db.Users on new { patientid = p.id, p.primarycontactid} equals { u.patientid, primarycontactid = u.id}
    from u in userPatient.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join b in db.BillingSettings on b.PracticeId equals p.id
    where p.status == 1 &&
        p.appointmentdate > now && p.appointmentdate < now.AddDays(90) &&
        (b == null || (b.isDue == 1 && b.expirationdate < now))
    orderby p.id
    select new
    {
        p.id,
        p.code,
        email = u.email
        date = b.date 
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ isn't embedded SQL, it's a query language for an ORM. ORMs deal with objects, not tables. The ORM itself, EF, will generate any JOINs based on the *entities* and their relations. To give a good answer one would need to know what the actual entities look like.

Assuming a Patient has a `User` and `BillingSetting` property, the LINQ query could be something like:

```
var overduePatients= context.Patients
                    .Where(p=>p.AppointmentDate > DateTime.Today && 
                              p.AppointmentDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(90) &&
                              p.BillingSetting.ExpiratonDate < DateTime.Today 
                              && p.BillingSetting.IsDue)
                    .Select(p=>new { p.Id, 
                                     p.Code, 
                                     p.User.Email,
                                     p.BillingSetting.Date
                                   });
```

No explicit JOINS are needed. EF Core will generate those from the `Patient.BillingSettings` and `Patient.User` navigation properties and their metadata.

The generated query will pass the date values as parameters, not product-specific calls like `GetDate()` or `Now()`

If `BillingSettings` is a 1-Many relation, it means we really want the overdue bills, not the patients. The query will have to start from the bills in that case :

```
var overdueBills= context.BillingSettings
                    .Where(b=>b.Patient.AppointmentDate > DateTime.Today && 
                              b.Patient.AppointmentDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(90) &&
                              b.ExpiratonDate < DateTime.Today 
                              && b.IsDue)
                    .Select(b=>new { b.Patient.Id, 
                                     b.Patient.Code, 
                                     b.Patient.User.Email,
                                     b.Date
                                   });
```